Typescript importing types with regular import
Foo.ts:
export type Foo = {}

Bar.ts (compiles fine):
import { Foo } from './foo.js'

const foo: Foo = {}

Bar2.ts:
import { Foo } from './foo.js'
export { Foo }

Error:
SyntaxError: The requested module './foo.js' does not provide an export named 'Foo'

Why does export statement result in import not working? Using import { type Foo } works fine but considering VSCode auto import declares everything as regular imports, surely this should still work?

I don't get a compilation error with your example (on TS version 4.9.5). I wonder if the issue is how the import is done and maybe the location of the files. Do you still get an error if you replace './foo.js;' with './foo;'?

I'm using tsx for what it's worth. Not sure if I was getting this before with ts-node but it doesn't work on node 22.

Started a blank project with node 22.11.0 and TS 5.7.2 (doing npm install typescript and npx tsc --init. Created the 3 files you shared, compiled them with npx tsc and got no errors.

tsx not npx tsc. But indeed I can't seem to replicate it on a clean project after copying my tsconfig, not sure what's wrong :|

Based on the question
We have 3 files: Foo.ts, Bar.ts and Bar2.ts.
So ./foo.js is it a black box or a typo. Maybe this file just doesn't exist.
A little bit about import/export
Better use explicit import type/export type if you're working with types.
The compiler tries to find an exported value so that when compiling it, it can be written to the final bundle or to .js files.
IDE problem
VSCode supports TypeScript out of the box, but as far as I have worked with it, each time it had different problems, especially in imports and exports, which it either tries to combine or does not use at all.
It may help to switch to WebStorm for TypeScript projects, because it supports
auto explicit import type/export type stuff.

You have to import typescript files as .js. Makes no sense but that's how it is. There is a flag to allow importing them with correct extension but it only works if you also set it to emit declarations only.
